# HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403:"{"timestamp":"2023-07-31T09:20:40.414+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","path":"/users/session-logout"}

Tags: java

I am getting the above exception while trying to implement user logout service in Spring boot application.

**ValidateUserServiceImple.Java**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/logoff-user")
public String userSignOut(@Validated @RequestBody UserSignOutRequest userSignOutJsonRequest)
throws EnrollmentServiceException {
   return validateUserBusinessServiceImpl.userSignOut(userSignOutJsonRequest);
}
```

**UserOperationServiceHandler.java**

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;
@Value("${oauth.session.logout.url}")
private String logoutUrl;
public String userSignOut(UserSignOutRequest userSignOutJsonRequest) {
    return QuoteServiceUtil.logOffSession(restTemplate, userSignOutJsonRequest, logoutUrl);
}
```

**LogoutServiceUtil.java**

```
public static String logOffSession(RestTemplate restTemplate, UserSignOutRequest userRequest, String sessionUrl){
    try {
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.set(EnrollmentConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, EnrollmentConstants.WWW_URL_ENCODED);
      MultiValueMap<String, String> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
      request.add("accesstoken", userRequest.getAccessToken());
      return doPostCall(restTemplate, sessionUrl, headers, request);
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
      LOGGER.error(EnrollmentConstants.EXCEPTION_OCCURRED, e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the title, the URL is `session-logout` in your rest API its `/logoff-user` which one you are using. Check your security configuration that is it configured properly.